# How do I trigger functions in both the child AND parent component using Event Emitters?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, eventemitter

I have a parent and child component, and I want the parent to be able to trigger a function in the child, while also allowing the child to trigger one in the parent. Here's what I'm doing for the child to trigger a function in the parent:

Child

```
@Output() callParentFunction = new EventEmitter<any>();
...
this.callParentFunction.emit();
```

Parent

```
  template: `
    <child-component
      (callParentFunction)="parentfunction($event)"
    >
    </child-component>
  `
```

This works to trigger `parentfunction` but how do I go in the other direction? I need a child function to be triggered with an event emitter from the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

parent

```
template: `
    <child-component
      [events]="eventsSubject.asObservable()"
    >
    </child-component>
  `
private eventsSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
anyfunction(){  
    this.eventsSubject.next()
 }
```

child

```
@Input() events: Observable<void>;
ngOnInit() {        
  this.events.subscribe(() => 
  //do something
 );   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngOnChanges()`. So you can and handle .

[As Angular docs says:](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

> A callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change
>   detector has checked data-bound properties if at least one has
>   changed, and before the view and content children are checked.

```
@Component({selector: 'child', template: `...`})
class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  // TODO(issue/24571): remove '!'.
  @Input()
  prop: number;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }
}
```

and then from parent component update some object `foo` and then `ngOnChanges` method will be triggered:

```
<child-component
  [events]="eventsSubject.asObservable()"
  [prop] = "foo"
>
</child-component>
```